# How to load a activity only when all the imageViews are loaded using Picasso

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am trying to make a app where there are two activity..
First activity have all images loaded using Picasso in a `RecyclerView`,When clicked it will take to second activity, which will enlarge the clicked picture. Again there is a another `RecyclerView` which will show other random images to pick from...

I just want to know how to load the second activity only after every photos are loaded in the first activity,else the screen looks blank and ugly.

Comment: its a bad idea, in case image loading fails user will be stuck in app.

Comment: don't prevent new Activity to launch, instead, you can try some placeholders or ProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can using Picasso loading callback

```
Picasso.with(YourActivity.this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            // can click to open second activity

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            //do smth when there is picture loading error
                        }
                    });
```